# Actualizar un valor desde la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, sql

estoy teniendo un error al intentar actualizar alguna columna de algún usuario pero me está dando error, ¿Qué podría hacer para solucionarlo, este es mi código, pero al intentar hacer un "echo" de la variable no aparece nada, ni tampoco realiza cambios en la base de datos, ¿Cual es el problema?

```
    if (isset($_POST['submitredes'])) {
    $facebook = $_POST['facebook'];
    $twitter = $_POST['twitter'];
    $youtube = $_POST['youtube'];
    $twitch = $_POST['twitch'];
    $userids = $resultado1['id'];
    
            $sqlss = "UPDATE users SET facebook='$facebook', twitter='$twitter', youtube='$youtube', twitch='$twitch' WHERE id='$userids'";
            $resultsss = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlss);
            echo $resultsss;
            die();
            if ($resultsss) {
                $facebook = "";
                $twitter = "";
                $youtube = "";
                $twitch = "";
            }
        
}
```

Comment: Empieza a leer las variables que ingresan al isset, si desde ahi no te muestra info, es porque no estás recibiendo datos del formulario.

Comment: @JheymanMejia estoy obteniendo correctamente los datos que hay en las variables que ingresan al isset, pero lo que no estoy podiendo realizar es actualizarlo desde la base de datos, no realiza ningún cambio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que cuando tomas los datos que vienen del post el "$userids = $resultado1['id'];" no lo tomas de este POST. Te recomiendo que le hagas un echo al $sqlss para que veas toda la sentencia SQL y los valores que estab cargados y la misma la apliques en phpmyadmin.

```
if (isset($_POST['submitredes'])) {
$facebook = $_POST['facebook'];
$twitter = $_POST['twitter'];
$youtube = $_POST['youtube'];
$twitch = $_POST['twitch'];
$userids = $resultado1['id']; <-- aqui deberias de tomar el POST
```

Comment: El $userids, es para obtener la id del usuario ya logueado, mi idea es que el usuario pueda actualizar sus valores desde la base de datos, y que tome lo que ingresó el usuario desde el input text y lo actualize

Comment: Colocale el echo donde te dije ($sqlss) para ver que datos se forman en el update, y pasalo por el PHPMYADMIN para ver si el error esta alli.

Comment: ```UPDATE users SET facebook='s', twitter=' s', youtube=' s', twitch=' s' WHERE id='1' (esto es el echo)``` yo lo veo correctamente, hasta funciona muy bien desde el phpmyadmin, ¿algo más que pueda hacer?

Comment: Por favor has un `var_dump($resultsss);` en vez de un echo, (comenta el echo), ahora vamos a ver si el error es de conexion.

Comment: me aparece esto bool(false)

Comment: Tambien podrias cambiar la ejecucion con este codigo `$resultsss = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlss) or trigger_error("Error de MySQL: " . mysqli_error($conn));` seria una mejor forma de visualizar si tienen un error en conexion.

Comment: me aparece que es un error de MySQL ("Error de MySQL")

Comment: Entonces es error de conexion.

Comment: Puedes validarlo tu mismo o colocarlo aqui.

Comment: ```$conn = new mysqli($localhost,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);``` tengo esto como la variable $conn, y la información de conexión es correcta, ya que estoy utilizando esa misma variable con otra función y funciona.

Comment: Si el error que te arroja es **bool(false)**  es posible que tu campo de id en Base de datos sean numerico (estas pasando todos los datos como texto/string) trata de colocar tu `WHERE id = '" . $userids . "'";`

Comment: Muchas gracias, igual ya lo pude resolver de otra manera :#

Comment: Si pudiste resolverlo, seria bueno que respondas a tu pregunta. Puede que en un futuro le sirva a alguien que tenga un problema similar :)